# C++ cout in VS Code is not printing the value of variable

Tags: c++, cout

When I click on run, after the first line , the program terminates without printing the value of 'age'.

```
# include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int age = 4;
    cout<<"dbcuhdihidh"<<age<<"ashsbcjsahcij"<<endl;
}
```

[image: Just look at the output 4 is not printed]

Comment: I’m not used to your settings, but it looks like you are running an older version of your program. Recompile.

Comment: You have a space between # and iostream

Answer (score 1):

Recompile your program, this works perfectly fine.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.